# Order rows in a custom repeating pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to order rows in a custom pattern. For example:
lets say I have a table(Id, type, createdDate) with type column values of A, B, C. I want the result set to be in the repeating pattern of 
B B C A, ordered by createdDate within the type. Thanks!
Here is an example

**Table**

```
1   |   A   |   2017-1-20
2   |   A   |   2017-1-19
3   |   B   |   2017-1-21
4   |   B   |   2017-1-22
5   |   B   |   2017-1-23
6   |   C   |   2017-2-20
7   |   B   |   2017-2-19
8   |   B   |   2017-2-21
9   |   A   |   2017-2-22
10  |   A   |   2017-2-23
11  |   B   |   2017-2-20
```

The table above can be seen as three sets of data ordered by CreatedDate.

```
2   |   A   |   2017-1-19
1   |   A   |   2017-1-20
9   |   A   |   2017-2-22
10  |   A   |   2017-2-23


3   |   B   |   2017-1-21
4   |   B   |   2017-1-22
5   |   B   |   2017-1-23
7   |   B   |   2017-2-19
11  |   B   |   2017-2-20
8   |   B   |   2017-2-21


6   |   C   |   2017-2-20
```

The result set should be ordered according to the pattern and the createdDate.

**Result**

```
3   |   B   |   2017-1-21
4   |   B   |   2017-1-22
6   |   C   |   2017-1-20
2   |   A   |   2017-1-19

5   |   B   |   2017-1-23
7   |   B   |   2017-2-19
1   |   A   |   2017-1-20

11  |   B   |   2017-2-20
8   |   B   |   2017-2-21
9   |   A   |   2017-2-22

10  |   A   |   2017-2-23
```

We could think of the input table as three sets ordered by date. We have to merge them in the pattern of B B C A( This is an example, the pattern is flexible).

Comment: Elaborate your example and give sample data and expected output in tabular format.

Comment: Add some more rows to your example.

Comment: Is it an acceptable result, if the rows with ids **3** and **5** are swapped ? According to your description there is more than one possible result.

Comment: The rows are ordered by createDate within a Type. So rows 3 and 5 cannot be swapped.